# поднять прокси сервер win 10

Tags: прокси

Требуется поднять прокси сервер на домашнем компьютере, для того, чтобы можно было мой IP использовать, как прокси удаленно. Делал так, как показано здесь http://skesov.ru/kak-podnyat-prosteyshiy-proksi-server-na-windows/ с помощью программы 3proxy.
Не работает. Могут ли проблемы быть из-за того, что компьютер подключен через роутер и IP статический серый?

Comment: у вас должен быть белый ip и если он на роутере то до компа должна быть проброска портов или DMZ (в настройках роутера)

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы работал прокси сервер нужен доступ к твоему компьютеру. Для этого у тебя должен быть белый IP адрес. Если ты подключен к интернету через роутер, то тебе нежно настроить Static NAT на роутере. Поскольку количество белых IP адресов ограничено провайдеры берут за них определенную плату. Для обеспечения высокой доступности сервера рекомендую присмотреть себе VDS сервер. Они стоят не дорого и позволит избежать проблем в будущем

Answer (score 0):

Получил белый ip. В командной строке ввёл ipconfig и взял IPv4-адрес, который и указал в DMZ. Все заработало.